# does impala support the "window xxx as" syntax?

Tags: hive, window, impala

I'm on a CDH5.13 with hive-1.1 and impala-2.10.
And I found the following sql works well on hive and wrong in impala :

```
SELECT name,sum(age) OVER w, avg(age) OVER w FROM test1 WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY age DESC);
```

And the error msg:

select name,sum(age) OVER w, avg(age) OVER w FROM test...
                          ^
Encountered: IDENTIFIER
Expected: (

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: Can you try without using window clause. It should work fine. Window clause. It should work fine. Impala support windowing functions but not sure about Window clause.

Comment: Yes,that works fine,but that's little verbose.Thanks all the same.